# Lambda expression help

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I have a question how to write a lambda expression, i have it working in a mssql query like this:

```
SELECT KUNDNR 
FROM halldb.dbo.KUND
wWHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
    SELECT KundID 
    FROM halldb.dbo.KundInfo 
    WHERE KUNDNR = CONVERT(Varchar(50), KundInfo.KundID)
)
ORDER BY KUNDNR
```

And what i was trying using lambda expression was this:

```
db.KUNDs.Select(x => x).Except(db.KundInfos.Select(x => x));
```

But since KUNDs and KundInfo is two different kind of objects that wont work...i could go like this:

```
db.KUNDs.Select(x => x.KUNDNR).Except(db.KundInfos.Select(x => x.KundID.ToString()));
```

But that would just give me a list with strings with KUNDs.KUNDNR when i would really like to get a list with KUNDs objects back.

How can i do this?

Help would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
db.KUNDs.Where(k => !db.KundInfos.Any(ki => k.KUNDNR == ki.KundID.ToString()))
        .OrderBy(k => k.KUNDNR);
```

Comment: That throws an error " 'bool' does not contain a definition for 'OrderBy' and no extension method 'OrderBy' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found"

Comment: There was a missing closing parenthesis before `.OrderBy(k => k.KUNDNR)`. Sorry for that, the `OrderBy(` should be applied to the result of `Where(`.

Comment: Yup i just got it to work after i noticed your reply, thanx alot for help i have been struggling with this forever and ever!